# I am confused on how to create a new thread which displays the time to the clients

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, networking, pthreads

I am having trouble sending the time to the clients! I know how to display the time on the server but I don't know how to create another thread for the chat server that broadcasts current system time to all connected
clients. I know that in order create a thread you need to use:

```
pthread_t newClient;
pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *arg);
```

I am confused on how to display the time to the clients.

I am planning to use this code (in my server code) to display the time every five seconds:

```
time_t tm = time();
if (time()-tm>=5) {
    char buffer[256],buff[255]; 
    time_t   now;
    struct tm *ts;
    now = time(0);
    ts = localtime(&now);
    strftime(buff, sizeof(buff), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", ts);
    printf("%s\n", buff);
    tm = time();
}
```

Here are the threads I made for the clients (code from server):

```
if( pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL ,  func , (void*) &connfd) < 0)
{
    perror("could not create thread");
    return 1;
}

if( pthread_create( &jointhread_id , NULL ,  join , (void*) &thread_id) < 0)
{
    perror("could not create thread");
    return 1;
}
```

Any guidance will be helpful.

Client code :

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#define MAX 80 
#define PORT 8080 
#define SA struct sockaddr
void func(int sockfd)
{
    char buff[MAX];
    int n;
    for (;;) {
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        printf("Enter the string : ");
        n = 0;
        while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n')
            ;
        write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
        printf("From Server : %s", buff);
        if ((strncmp(buff, "exit", 4)) == 0) {
            printf("Client Exit...\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int sockfd, connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;
    
    // socket create and verification
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    
    // assign IP, PORT
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    
    // connect the client socket to server socket
    if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) {
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("connected to the server..\n");
    
    // function for chat
    func(sockfd);
    
    // close the socket
    close(sockfd);
}
```